# Query on array on a nested document with pymongodb

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I am building a chat program
And in the backend, I have

```
chatcol.insert({ "chatid": "133235", "messages": [ {"from": "user3", "content": "Hello", "time": "20101213T172215"},  {"from": "user2", "content": "Hi", "time": "20101214T172215"} ] })

chatcol.insert({ "chatid": "134735", "messages": [ {"from": "user2", "content": "Hello", "time": "20101217T172215"},  {"from": "user12", "content": "Hi", "time": "20101213T172215"} ] })
```

Since there can be a lot of messages, I want the server only give the new message the client didnt see.
The client will give me a lastuptime, the time where they last logon.
I want to find chats with only the new message only.

How do I write such query?

Comment: Is the `time` field a **Date** or **Timestamp** field?

Comment: timestamp. I have ISO timestamp representation here, but I am find with any representation, as long as it represents a timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have considered `time` as `ISODate()`
Also, `lastuptime` given by the client wil be `ISODate()`

**collection**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da31a63c35040d7fbf1db3c"),
    "chatid" : "133235",
    "messages" : [
        {
            "from" : "user3",
            "content" : "Hello",
            "time" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "from" : "user2",
            "content" : "Hi",
            "time" : ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da31ab2c35040d7fbf1db3d"),
    "chatid" : "133235",
    "messages" : [
        {
            "from" : "user2",
            "content" : "Hello",
            "time" : ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "from" : "user12",
            "content" : "Hi",
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

There are two scenarios. Depending on your use-case, select the appropriate:

**1**. Fetch `chats` where any one of the messages has `time` `>=` `lastuptime`

```js
db.chatcol.find({'messages.time': {"$gte": ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da31a63c35040d7fbf1db3c"),
    "chatid" : "133235",
    "messages" : [
        {
            "from" : "user3",
            "content" : "Hello",
            "time" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "from" : "user2",
            "content" : "Hi",
            "time" : ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da31ab2c35040d7fbf1db3d"),
    "chatid" : "133235",
    "messages" : [
        {
            "from" : "user2",
            "content" : "Hello",
            "time" : ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "from" : "user12",
            "content" : "Hi",
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**2**. Fetch `messages` where `time` `>=` `lastuptime`
This one flattens the `message` `array`

```js
db.chatcol.aggregate([
{ $unwind :'$messages'},
{ $match : {"messages.time": { "$gte": ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") }}}
])
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da31a63c35040d7fbf1db3c"),
    "chatid" : "133235",
    "messages" : {
        "from" : "user2",
        "content" : "Hi",
        "time" : ISODate("2018-05-01T00:00:00Z")
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da31ab2c35040d7fbf1db3d"),
    "chatid" : "133235",
    "messages" : {
        "from" : "user12",
        "content" : "Hi",
        "time" : ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00Z")
    }
}
```

**Note**: Map the `$gte` query according to your `lastuptime`

Comment: Thank you so much! If you dont mind, I would like to give you a hug

Comment: @HairyAss Welcome buddy :)